# CSS fold out menu not closing after clicking

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple fold out menu. When I click on menu icon, the menu opens.

Now when I click on any option, it should get closed which is not happening. Below is my code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ersaurabh101/pen/yjaOgv).

I would prefer to solve this using CSS only. I do not wish to use JS.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* make it look decent enough */
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 2;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
     * Just a quick hamburger
     */

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/*
     * Transform all the slices of hamburger
     * into a crossmark.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}


/*
     * But let's hide the middle one.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/*
     * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
     * Make this absolute positioned
     * at the top left of the screen
     */

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/*
     * And let's slide it in from the left
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
        A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
        so you can use the :checked selector on it.
        -->
    <input type="checkbox" />


    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>


    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>About</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Info</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank">
        <li>Show me more</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Of course this isn’t happening, because clicking a link does nothing to affect the state of a checkbox. _“Please provide solution using css only. I do not wish to use js”_ - sorry, but that is rather nonsense to begin with - especially (but not limited to) regarding accessibility.

Comment: can you help me get it soughted out ? I need to close this on a click

Comment: There _is_ no (proper) sorting this out using CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the size of the hidden `<input type="checkbox"/>` to make it cover all menu elements.

Though this ruins the hover-effect.

Otherwise you must use javascript.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* make it look decent enough */
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 2;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
     * Just a quick hamburger
     */

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/*
     * Transform all the slices of hamburger
     * into a crossmark.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}


/*
     * But let's hide the middle one.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/*
     * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
     * Make this absolute positioned
     * at the top left of the screen
     */

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/*
     * And let's slide it in from the left
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}

#menuToggle input:checked {
  width: 300px;
  height: 290px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
        A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
        so you can use the :checked selector on it.
        -->
    <input type="checkbox" />


    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>


    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>About</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Info</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank">
        <li>Show me more</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Using javascript makes it quite easy to achieve it by unchecking the checkbox on every `<li>` click

```js
var $input = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
var $$menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li');

$$menuLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $input.checked = false;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* make it look decent enough */
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 2;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
     * Just a quick hamburger
     */

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/*
     * Transform all the slices of hamburger
     * into a crossmark.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}


/*
     * But let's hide the middle one.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/*
     * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
     * Make this absolute positioned
     * at the top left of the screen
     */

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/*
     * And let's slide it in from the left
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
        A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
        so you can use the :checked selector on it.
        -->
    <input type="checkbox" />


    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>


    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>About</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Info</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank">
        <li>Show me more</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If this is not the right way then I am ok using js, please guide me the best solution to achieve this

Comment: @user2828442 see Update

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g4Lv64ee/
Of course you can, but its basically the same as running the code snippet